# Get plugin version installed in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, apache-kafka

Is there any way to find the specific logstash plugin version ?

I'm able to list the plugin using `bin/logstash-plugin list 'logstash-input-kafka'`, and in help of `bin/logstash-plugin`, I wasn't able to find any flags to find the version of plugin installed in logstash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find the version of a plugin, you can list the `vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/` folder and you'll see the plugin versions you're running. For instance, on Logstash 2.3.2, you'd see this for the `logstash-input-kafka` plugin:

```
ls -la vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems | grep "logstash-input-kafka"
> logstash-input-kafka-2.0.8
```

You can also find the version number in the `gemspec` file inside the plugin folder.

To find the logstash version:

With Logstash 2.x, you can run this:

```
bin/logstash version
```

With Logstash 5.x (still in alpha stage), you can run this:

```
bin/logstash -V
```

**UPDATE**

In the meantime, I found the `--verbose` flag [documented here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.3/working-with-plugins.html#listing-plugins). You can also append a specific plugin name. It goes like this:

```
bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose logstash-input-kafka
```

Will yield

```
logstash-input-kafka (2.0.8)
```

Comment: Thanks Val, but I was looking for but a plugin version installed in logstash not logstash.

Updated question title, just to make it more clear

Comment: I was updating the answer ;-)

Comment: this one is bit more clear than previous one, i think there should be a option in `bin/logstash-plugin` to check that.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yes, I agree, feel free to [submit an issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues) to request that feature.

Comment: I was about to do that, in-fact I was thinking of making contribution in repo ;-)

Answer (score 2):

@Val answer still works, you can do it via existing flags in `bin/logstash-plugin`:

`bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose logstash-input-kafka` **or**

`bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose kafka`

Thanks to: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5816#issuecomment-241966409